# Creating Teams meetings in PowerShell with Graph

Tags: powershell, csv, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

My question is in two parts.
First, I have been trying to create meetings in MS Teams through PowerShell. I am able to connect to the MgGraph module using

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "Calendars.ReadWrite"
```

but when I run my script, I continually get permissions errors. Am I assigning the correct permissions when I connect, or is there something I am missing?

Also, I will need to run this script for many classes, so I have been using a .csv to populate most fields. start/end time is in "2022-11-29T00:00:00" format. Will this template be sufficient to create multiple Teams meetings for multiple classes?

```
$Students = Import-CSV “Import_Meeting.csv” 

ForEach($team in $Students){ 
$GroupId = $team.GroupID
$startTime = $team.Section1
$endTime = $team.Section2
$Repeat = $team.Recurrence
$startDate = $team.ClassStart 
$endDate = $team.ClassEnd 


$params = @{ 
Subject = "Test Class Meeting" 
Body = @{ 
ContentType = "HTML" 
Content = "Does this work for you?" 
} 

Start = @{ 
DateTime = $startTime 
TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time" 
} 

End = @{ 
DateTime = $endTime 
TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time" 
} 

Recurrence = @{ 
    Pattern = @{ 
    Type = "weekly" 
    Interval = 1 
    DaysOfWeek = @($Repeat) 
    } 
    Range = @{ 
    Type = "endDate" 
    StartDate = $startDate 
    EndDate = $endDate 
    } 
}


AllowNewTimeProposals = $false 
IsOnlineMeeting = $true 
OnlineMeetingProvider = "teamsForBusiness" 
} 
}

New-MgGroupEvent -GroupId $GroupId -BodyParameter $params
```

Comment: Could you please share the error log so that we can investigate from our end?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create an event for the group from the application running as a daemon which uses application permissions. This case is not supported according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#permissions).

[image]

If you are signed-in on behalf of user, then check if your admin has granted required permissions for the user in Azure Portal.

[image]