# Create Teams meeting by Microsoft Graph or other means

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams

I'd like to create MS Teams meetings from another application.
The Teams application is running on the computer, outlook is not used though.
How would I accomplish this the best / easiest way without (much) user interaction?

As far as I can see, the best option would be to use the REST API to create a meeting using the api-URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events.
If I can also create a meeting commandline or by COM objects or something else, I could do that, too.

So here would be what I did for research with graph so far:
I can log on to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and use my user to create meetings and get the response. To do that, I modified the permission to read / read-write the calendar. If I copy the access token and use it with a powershell Invoke-RestMethod, it also does what I want. I can do the same with Connect-Graph -Scopes "Calendars.ReadWrite". But it would show this big browser windows about the login as X.

I read about apps, but if I use the apps ID and so on to log in silently, it seems like I am not in the current user scope but in a process scope and that's different. At least I set the API permissions up to also have access to Calendars.ReadWrite via Microsoft Graph, but I get an Access denied error if I try to run the same New-MgUserEvent to create a meeting for the current user (that is running the local powershell).

If use the token with Connect-MgGraph, it displays the client and tenantID and the ContextScope is process, not current user, so that would fit.

If I understand it correctly, I could use the token to get another one for a user... (reference is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user )
If I use the Connect-Graph -ForceRefresh parameter (which I guess would do the same, the popup tells me I'm logged in as the current user (not process).

This is a bit odd, so before I try to use the rest api and fumble a bit around:
Can I use the example from the link to refresh the token to get a user token that has the rights that I defined (and be able to access the calendar)?
Or is there some misunderstanding on my part?

Would it be a better idea to just use something like powershell, have the user log in once per day and leave the process in the background and create the new entries from there?
Do you have to refresh a token when you use connect-graph? Or could that be done better by Rest web api, if I can export the token?

The idea of having an app that would have access to all calendars would seem like a bigger security risk and I'd kind of want to avoid that. If I could configure the apps to have access to only one specific calendar, that would be cool, too. But I did not find it when looking around.

Thanks and best regards to all that took their time to read and consider to help.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617325/creating-teams-meetings-in-powershell-with-graph

Comment: `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Calendars.ReadWrite` will stay connected until you `Disconnect-MgGraph`, and will refresh it's own token as needed up to 90 days I think. It's stored outside powershell, so you don't have to keep it running. It should only have to prompt for consent **once** (unless you grant delegated consent as admin, then no prompting for assigned users and groups). Delegated permissions means users can only access what their user can see (their own calendar), unless you specifically grant All like `user.read.all`.